# Is there a cut of Prometheus including the missing scenes (fan-made, perhaps)?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

I'm a big fan of Alien, and I've the Prometheus collector edition (Including Alien Quadrilogy and Prometheus), but in the box, there is only a separate Blu-Ray with all the cut scenes in a single video, after some searching, I found some information about Ridley Scott, who doesn't want to do a Director's Cut.

Is there a way to see the movie + the cut scenes, even if it's a fan made montage?

Comment: Since several of the deleted scenes openly contradict the events of the theatrical version, the answer is likely to be "no".

Comment: Oh, I know that this movie is not liked by the fans, but personally I like it, and I think it will be nice to see a Director's Cut, someday..

Comment: Really? I got the feeling that most people, Alien fans or otherwise, have a generally positive view of Prometheus.

And, if you want it bad enough, why not try to remix your own fan-edit with some of the cutscenes spliced in? You'd probably have to either skip the scenes that break the events in the theatrical version or replace/cut some theatrical scenes out, but you could probably figure out where to logically put at least some of the deleted scenes (unless it's very early raw footage that was taken out because the film evolved in a completely different direction).

Comment: Prometheus Redux: The Good Version.

Answer (score 6):

There are three [fan edits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_edit) that incorporate deleted scenes, however they make many other changes as well and do not necessarily use all the new material available.

Here they are with brief synopsis:

1. **[Prometheus: Giftbearer](http://www.fanedit.org/ifdb/component/content/article/79-fanedit-listings/fanfix/869-prometheus-giftbearer) (February 2013)**

> Incorporated deleted, alternate and supplementary footage and made
>   numerous edits to original scenes to strengthen story, clarify
>   character motivation, and address some often-mentioned issues viewers
>   had with the original theatrical release.

2. **[Prometheus – Special Edition](http://www.fanedit.org/ifdb/component/content/article/79-fanedit-listings/fanfix/903-prometheus-special-edition) (May 2013)**

> Prometheus SE cuts out a lot of the unnecessary humor, dialog and
>   scene's, building stronger, smarter characters. Removing many plot
>   holes with the story and just general things that have issues. Such as
>   Fifield getting lost in the structure, running in a straight line away
>   from a rolling space craft. Deleted scene's or certain shots from the
>   deleted footage was re-integrated back into the movie by either using
>   several shots to change certain scene's or by adding a whole new scene
>   to the film. All new material was color corrected, scored, sfx added
>   and leveled to appropriate audio levels.

3. **[Prometheus Unbound](http://www.fanedit.org/ifdb/component/content/article/79-fanedit-listings/fanfix/960-prometheus-unbound) (November 2013)**

> Highlights of the edit include the following:
>
> The opening sequence with the first Engineer has been all but replaced
>   with the opening Ted Talk followed by a montage courtesy of Tree of
>   Life. Holloway's douchy-ness has been seriously reduced, Shaw no
>   longer makes faith-based decisions and Vickes' bitchiness has been
>   mostly removed. No more exploding head and the attack on Fifield and
>   Milburn has less idiocy on their part. The ship falls on Vickes
>   without giving her time enough to "just make a right turn."

All three are available on [fanedit.info](http://fanedit.info/fanedits/). Note that the legality of sharing/downloading fan edits is questionable. You can find more info on that on the above-linked Wikipedia page. There is a [download guide on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/fanedits/comments/2fgy72/a_brief_primer_on_how_to_find_and_download/).